Getting Memory Error When try to upload large file with react-native-fs in react native Expo
The primary reason was that I wanted to upload in chunks, so I read the file and divided it into chunks.
RNFS.readFile(fileUri, length, offset, 'base64');
similar to the method I described previously, the issue is that it reads the entire file rather than chunks of it, so when I try to read a large file, it stores the entire file in memory and causes me to have memory problems.
In order to save memory and ensure that my enormous video uploads smoothly, I would like to read files in chunks only, and only one chunk at a time store in memory.
